# Javascript string update doesn't change the string itself

Tags: javascript

I have following simple javascript code:

```
s="hello"
s[0]="X"
console.log(s[0])
```

The output is `h`, but I have updated it as `X`, I would ask why I got such result, thanks.

Comment: Strings are immutable, you can't edit them you can create a new like `s = "X" + s.substring(1)`

Comment: Add `'use strict';` at the top of your script and you'll see the error (and likely more, over time). Also `console.print` isn't function, but I assume you mean `console.log`.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in JavaScript are [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive), which means they are immutable, ie. you are not able to change them. If you were running your code in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) then this would throw an error.

If you wanted to modify this string you would need to effectively create a copy of it, and then assign that to the `s` variable eg.

```
s = "X" + s.substring(1)
```